# Service Worker, double caching?

Tags: service-worker

Im having trouble with my Service Worker. I have implemented it with the Cache then Network technique, where content is first fetched from cache, and a network-fetch is always performed and the result is cached at success. (Inspired by this solution, [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/serviceworker-for-offline/))

When I make changes to my web app and hit refresh, I of course, the first time get the old content. But on subsequent refreshes the content alternates between old and new. I can get new or old content five times in a row or it could differ on each request.

I have been debugging the Service Worker for a while now and does not get any wiser. Does anyone have an idea about whats wrong with the implementation?

**EDIT:**

```
var version = 'v1::2';

self.addEventListener("install", function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(
      caches
        .open(version + 'fundamentals')
        .then(function (cache) {
            return cache.addAll([
                "/"
            ]);
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {

    if (event.request.method !== 'GET') {
        return;
    }
    event.respondWith(
      caches
        .match(event.request)
        .then(function (cached) {
            var networked = fetch(event.request)
              .then(fetchedFromNetwork, unableToResolve)
              .catch(unableToResolve);

            return cached || networked;

            function fetchedFromNetwork(response) {
                var cacheCopy = response.clone();

                caches
                  .open(version + 'pages')
                  .then(function add(cache) {
                      cache.put(event.request, cacheCopy);
                  });

                return response;
            }

            function unableToResolve() {

                return new Response('<h1>Service Unavailable</h1>', {
                    status: 503,
                    statusText: 'Service Unavailable',
                    headers: new Headers({
                        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
                    })
                });
            }
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener("activate", function (event) {

    event.waitUntil(
      caches
        .keys()
        .then(function (keys) {
            return Promise.all(
              keys
                .filter(function (key) {
                    return !key.startsWith(version);
                })
                .map(function (key) {
                    return caches.delete(key);
                })
            );
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: I think you'll need to do a bit more digging to find out about exactly what's going on. Can you reproduce this behavior in an incognito window or private browsing mode? Using debugging tools, can you see the requests hitting the service worker?

Comment: It is possible but unlikely the cache after network code is not completing but pelase, paste your specific code and let us take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you are setting the version, but I presume multiple caches still exist (I can see you are trying to delete the previous caches but still). [caches.match() is a convenience method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage/match) and the order is not guaranteed (at least Chrome seems to query **the oldest one** first). Chrome Developer Tools shows you the existing caches (Application/Cache/Cache Storage) and their contents. If you want to query a specific cache, you'll need to do:

```
caches.open(currentCacheName).then(function(cache) {...}
```

as [in the example in the Cache documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache).

Comment: I know the question is old but I ran into the same case head first and figured the answer might help others who come to this question for help